# Redirect alert on successful verification using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application in Codeigniter, My registration process involves users filling in there details which include an email address where after successful validation the user will be sent a verification code. This process works well but the only problem is when the user finishes the form and press register it loads and redirects to the login page without informing a user the code has been sent when it redirects to the login, how can I implement this? the below code is what I have so far

**Auth .php**

```
    // action create user method
public function actionCreate() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_no', 'Contact No', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of Birth(DD-MM-YYYY)', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->register();
    } else {
        $firstName = $this->input->post('first_name');
        $lastName = $this->input->post('last_name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $contactNo = $this->input->post('contact_no');
        $dob = $this->input->post('dob');
        $address = $this->input->post('address');
        $timeStamp = time();
        $status = 0;
        $verificationCode = uniqid();
        $verificationLink = site_url() . 'signin?usid=' . urlencode(base64_encode($verificationCode));
        $userName = $this->mail->generateUnique('users', trim($firstName . $lastName), 'user_name', NULL, NULL);
        $this->auth->setUserName($userName);
        $this->auth->setFirstName(trim($firstName));
        $this->auth->setLastName(trim($lastName));
        $this->auth->setEmail($email);
        $this->auth->setPassword($password);
        $this->auth->setContactNo($contactNo);
        $this->auth->setAddress($address);
        $this->auth->setDOB($dob);
        $this->auth->setVerificationCode($verificationCode);
        $this->auth->setTimeStamp($timeStamp);
        $this->auth->setStatus($status);
        $chk = $this->auth->create();
        if ($chk === TRUE) {
            $this->load->library('encryption');
            $mailData = array('topMsg' => 'Hi', 'bodyMsg' => 'Congratulations, Your registration has been successfully submitted.', 'thanksMsg' => SITE_DELIMETER_MSG, 'delimeter' => SITE_DELIMETER, 'verificationLink' => $verificationLink);
            $this->mail->setMailTo($email);
            $this->mail->setMailFrom(MAIL_FROM);
            $this->mail->setMailSubject('User Registeration!');
            $this->mail->setMailContent($mailData);
            $this->mail->setTemplateName('verification');
            $this->mail->setTemplatePath('mailTemplate/');
            $chkStatus = $this->mail->sendMail(MAILING_SERVICE_PROVIDER);
            if ($chkStatus === TRUE) {
                redirect('signin');
            } else {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: read about [Session Library flashdata](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#CI_Session::flashdata): set it when clicking register (before redirecting to Login). Once redirected to login, check if it exists, if it does, echo a message.

Comment: can I set it on the if chk statement in Auth.php, specifically if ($chk === TRUE) ?

Comment: wherever, in the line above where you redirect (and only if registration was complete, obviously)

Answer (score 1):

In your Register method before redirect to login

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('notify', 'Your code is sent');
redirect('auth/login');
```

in your login view - You can use Javascript with notifyJS or Bootstrap Notification to make design

```
if($this->session->flashdata('notify')){

   echo  $this->session->flashdata('notify');
}
```